# Combining Require.js, Backbone.js and a server side MVC framework

Tags: codeigniter, backbone.js, server-side

We're actually planning a really complex web application. At least for my own standards.
In the past we have always been using a combination of a server side MVC Framework (Codeigniter) and client side functionality (jQuery and plugins). We have simply written inline javascript code in our views. This worked as expected, but of course with several disadvantages:

- no caching
- duplicated js code
- maintainability issues
- ...

My main goal now is to organize the client side code in an efficient and easily maintainable way. But I want to stay with the server side MVC because of the existing know how and some existing interfaces. Furthermore I want to reduce complex DOM manipulation with jQuery and "spaghetti code".

Now I thought about a combination of Backbone.js and Require.js but I really can't find a tutorial or any solid description about how to combine them with a server side MVC.
Is it even recommended?

In my old apps I got a file structure like this:

- application (CodeIgniter)
- assets

  - js
  - css
  - imgs

Are there any ideas or best practices?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Backbone is a good choice, and Require is not mandatory here.

Require will just help you organize your source code and maybe improve performance. I think you can start right away with Backbone, which will be the thing you are going to use most, and add Require later.

Regarding Backbone, yes it's easy to use to use its Model with an existing MVC application, provided it returns JSON. To load your existing data you will want to use the [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) method combined to [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) to adapt to your existing code, or your own method.

Generally, think about which models are displayed in which views. Backbone helps you think this way : *I'm displaying Models represented as JSON data in Views which are made by HTML.*

Also, for the view layer, it's very easy to reuse your existing HTML, because views are not tied to anything, no JavaScript templating or nothing.

Simple example :

```
<div id="user">
    <span class="name">John</span>
</div>

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.$el('.name').html(this.model.get('name'));
    }
});
var userView = new UserView({el: $('#user')[0], model: ...});
```

In this example the `#user` div reflects the state of a `User` model, with its name.

Also check the [Todo App](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html) example in Backbone.

Comment: THX. How would you integrate Backbone? For example if I got a page ("server side" view) and several page elements (Backbone views). 

Is it possible to use a file per View/Model/Collection without having to inlcude each of them manually in the page. Is there some functionality in Backbone which allows you to load all the corresponding elements automatically?

Comment: You can of course define each Model/View/Collection in separate files, and you should definitely do that, but adding them manually or in one file will work out of the box, and you can add Require to achieve that later, with few lines of code. Make it work, make it right.

Comment: I have integrated Backbone with an existing MVC backend and it became easier once I stopped treating the server side code as MVC and more like an API. You are delegating the MVC properties to your front end; Backbone will now handle these aspects.

Comment: So your complete routing is done by Backbone and you only use the server side controllers for handling your data manipulation/reading?

How is it with the security if your doing the routing on the client side?

Comment: yes, we converted all the routing to be handled with backbone. this approach is entirely situational though. it works good for things like single page apps

Answer (score 4):

To add to mexique1's advice, it might be worth looking at the [backbone-boilerplate project](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate#readme). It should provide you best-practice solutions for many of the problems you're currently considering, such as the combination of require and backbone, the organisation of the client-side of your project, and the reduction of complex DOM manipulation (see templating).

The challenge, as you anticipate, will most likely be in combining the boilerplate approach with the approach you're used to. However, it will almost certainly be worth the effort since it should provide you a solid foundation for this and future projects.

Comment: The Backbone boilerplate project looks awesome !